# Is recursive parsing of include path in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-assist

I have issue with both "Go to definition" functionality on Visual Studio and "Go to Implementation" for Visual Assist plugin.

As I know, to perform jump to code I need to add additional include/source paths to the project property for MVS or sources paths for VAssist.

I have added them, but nothing changed. When I press go to definition I have following message:

[image: MsgBox with warning]

Is recursive parsing of include path that was added to additional paths?

Or I need to add all paths separately to that need for? If so, what to do with a very big number of paths within include/sources files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my own question. Seems like MS VS bug.
To enable proper jump, just need to turn of "Colorize inactive code blocks in a different color" check-box:

[image: Solution Image]